# Using Swipe view in drawer navigation

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, swipeview

I'm made a `navigation drawer` and the `listview` that I have is complete and now I decided with the main content to the right of it. However I had a  and now I'm gonna replace it with a swipe view. But **I can't find any swipe-view-in-drawer-navigation** tutorial anywhere.  I seen that on a bland activity you extends fragmentactivity but ive already extends something else due to my navigation with `ActionBarActivity`. So I don't know what to do now.

Please give me a hint

Comment: whatdo you mean by `swipeview`

Comment: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager @AbhishekBansal

Answer (score 0):

So essentially what you need a tutorial explaining ViewPager Implementation

here is one good [tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter)

Its very similar to `listview` and `adapter` implementation. You are going to have a view pager in your layout file like you have listview.

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/my_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Then you need a adapter and views to fill in that adapter. `FragmentPagerAdapter` will do that trick for you. This is usually how I implement this

```
        List<ViewPagerAdapter.FragmentTabItem> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    fragmentList.add(new ViewPagerAdapter.FragmentTabItem(MyFragmentOne.newInstance(),
            getString(R.string.one)));
    fragmentList.add(new ViewPagerAdapter.FragmentTabItem(MyFragmentTwo.newInstance(),
            getString(R.string.two)));

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter
            = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager() , fragmentList);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

here is my generic adapter implementation

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

List<FragmentTabItem> mFragmentTabItems;
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,
                        List<FragmentTabItem> fragmentTabItems) {
    super(fm);
    mFragmentTabItems = fragmentTabItems;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentTabItems.get(position % mFragmentTabItems.size()).getFragment();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(mFragmentTabItems != null)
        return mFragmentTabItems.size();
    else
        return 0;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTabItems.get(position % mFragmentTabItems.size()).getTitle();
}

public static class FragmentTabItem {
    @Getter
    @Setter Fragment fragment;
    @Getter @Setter
    String title;

    public FragmentTabItem(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.title = title;
    }
}}
```

Comment: So Actually I declare the object in mainActivity without extending anything there? or Do I need to extend mainActivity anyway? Sorry for my confusion

Comment: it doesn't matter what you extend your main activity from. Have a look at that tutorial. As I said earlier Its more or less same as listview implementation

Comment: Actually I'm trying to play several videos on the right side of the navigation drawer. and swipe to next video. Do I need a list? The mainActivity in the tutorial does Extend FragmentActivity? while I already extended something else

Comment: You will have to have URLs of those videos in a list or some other data structure.